# what is the type of deep learning algorithm in Rapidminer?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, data-mining, rapidminer

I use rapid-miner's deep learning operator for classification. But I can not find the type of deep learning algorithms.
Does Rapidminer use  Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) or Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs) or others?
Please help me.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is just a regular MLP (many layers of fully connected neurons), as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.rapidminer.com/studio/operators/modeling/predictive/neural_nets/deep_learning.html), no convolutions, recurrence or anything more complex, just good old MLP.

Comment: tanks for answer. how can I install this for rapisminer? https://github.com/LostSummer233/rapidminer-extension-dl4j-pack

Answer (score 3):

RapidMiner provides an H2O integration for  [multi-layer feed-forward artificial neural networks](https://docs.rapidminer.com/studio/operators/modeling/predictive/neural_nets/deep_learning.html).
There is also a new [Kerras extension](http://community.rapidminer.com/t5/RapidMiner-Studio-Knowledge-Base/Keras-Deep-Learning-extension/ta-p/40839) available which integrates an interface to the python library.

Regarding the DL4J project, you need to build the extension with gradle and then put the compiled *.jar file into the extension folder in your '.RapidMiner' folder.

Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the [RapidMiner community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com).